# dsPic33 or PIC24, how accurate float (32bit) and double (64bit) using arctan

Tags: math, floating-point, trigonometry, microchip

Angle= arctan(BY/BX)

I'm curious to know how accurate the trig calculation by Math.h library by above equation.

I have read the manual and not clearly specified its accuracy. I have looked into google search but no clear answer is found.

When angle goes toward to 0deg where numerator (BY) is small and denominator (BX) is large, where the By/BX term has low value, how the float (32 bit) and double (64 bit) is affected by this?.

I know 64 bit is more accurate but need to see performance difference between 32 bit and 64 bit floating point (0deg to 90deg) by this dsPIC33 or PIC24 MCU.

Is there rule how to use arctan for accurate calculation. One source suggest to work on 0deg to 45deg (0 to pi/4) for each 1/8 segment, this only apply to tan rather than arctan, correct?

Comment: Floating-point numbers are very good at accurately representing numbers near 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IEEE standard requires a maximal relative accuracy for all FP instructions, which means that all but the last bit of the mantissa (ignoring carry effects on previous bits) should be correct.

If you want to avoid the loss of precision while doing division (is there any?), then use, if available, the atan2 function.

---

**Update:** If you want to test the provided function against a theoretically correct version, you could use the following algorithm that uses bisection and the Taylor series of arctan for values from the sector `0<x && |y|<x`

```
partial_atan2(y,x) {
    r = sqrt(x*x+y*y);
    c = x/r;
    s = y/r;
    repeat 4 times {
        c = sqrt((1+c)/2);
        s = s/(2*c);
    }
    t = s/c;
    t2 = t*t;
    pow = -t2;
    sum = 1; 
    k = 3;
    while  1+abs(pow) > 1 {
        sum = sum + pow/k;
        pow = -pow*t2;
        k = k+2;
    }
    return 16*t*sum;
}
```

Comment: I have a hard time reconciling your first sentence with what I understand of the IEEE 754 standard. First, the IEEE 754 standard requires some operations to be correctly rounded, meaning that **all bits** of the significand are correct, for a meaning of “correct” that does not imply producing the mathematical result, since this result often cannot be represented. Elementary functions that cannot be required to be correctly rounded at the present state of the art have no accuracy requirements at all, although “faithful” (1 ULP of accuracy) is recommended because it is a good compromise.

Comment: Expressing accuracy in terms of correct bits is confusing (e.g. 0.111111 and 1.000000 differ in all 7 digits but represent numbers that differ only by 2^-6). It was acceptable for pen-and-paper computations, but there is no reason to use the digit as a unit of accuracy any more.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: If you post your technically more correct comments as answer, I would retract my answer.

Comment: Or reduce it to to the test method. As far as I understand, arithmetic operations and the square root have to be precise within 1/2 ULP, the other should be within 1 ULP for a reasonable domain. Obviously, sin and cos can never be precise for large arguments. They become meaningless for arguments x where x and x+1 are no longer distinguishable.

Comment: I more interested in proof of accuracy performance based on various test values along with provided results that is compared between 32 bit, 64 bit (in XC16 library) and 128 bit float from most precise machine, so I can see how ATAN2 actually performs and its limitation. I have read about IEEE 754 and tutorial in some way to describe the difference in 32 bit and 64 bit float. I prefer to see how ATAN2 actually performed rather than complex/vague statement from IEEE 754 document.

Comment: Then take a multi-precision calculator like bc to get a table of values with accuracy that surpasses the expected accuracy of your numbers. And exactly what numbers are you working with, 64bit double is the standard, 80bit extended is used in the FPU, I'm not sure if there is a 128bit floating point format.